# Redirecting from an iframe back into Ionic

Tags: cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I am creating a shop website with **ionic** that utilities an external payment provider that works in the standard way (runs in an **iframe** and redirects you back to your original page, once payment is successful).

As Ionic runs the website locally you can't just redirect back to a URL as each URL would be different.

I would imagine I am not the first person to come across this problem.

How can I redirect from my payment provider that is inside an iframe inside my app back to one of my ionic states?

Answer (score 1):

So you really shouldn't be using iframes in a cordova app at all. They provide really bad user experience. A better option would be to use the in-app-browser

Comment: Yeah I hear you but having to use cordova plugins slows development down because you lose the ability to use ionic serve

Comment: Not really since the inappbrowser functionality can be used in both browser and in cordova. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom url scheme for your application with this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I add a **listener in my main view**, waiting for a message from the iframe :

```
window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage, false);
```

And in the iframe, I **send a message** to the parent window :

```
parent.postMessage("stateToGo", "*");
```

Then, the callback method of the parent window is called :

```
 receiveMessage = (state) => {
   this.$state.go(state);
 }
```

Comment: Ok this looks promising - I will try this and let you know thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a similar kind of functionality in one of my apps using inAppBrowser. You can achieve this in the following way:

1. Implement a web application (not mobile web, just normal web using PHP or whatever..) which will take care of your payment processing.
2. On the initial page of your application, put a form that will be submitted to the payment gateway using JavaScript. You can fill the values in this form using GET URL parameters, or using "executeScript" method of inAppBrowser.
3. After the payment processing is done, the payment gateway calls a redirect URL and POST some data to it, which will be again a URL of your web application. Just echo the data as JSON string (because it will be easier to process in the application) on your webpage.
4. Once the inAppBrowser is completely redirected to your payment redirection URL, read the JSON string from inAppBrowser by using script "document.body.innerHTML".

Following code snippet can help you understand the approach:

```
    var ref = $window.open(order.payment_url, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=no'),
 processed = false;

            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {

                if (event.url === payment_result_url) {
                    ref.executeScript({
                        code: "document.body.innerHTML"
                    }, function (result) {
                        try {
                            var response = JSON.parse(result[0].replace(/\\/g, ""));
                            // Process payment result here
                        } catch (ex) {
                            // JSON parsing error
                        }
                        processed = true;
                        ref.close();
                    });
                }
            });

            ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function () {
                processed = true;
                ref.close();
                // Network error
            });
            ref.addEventListener('exit', function () {
                if (!processed) {
                    // Payment cancelled
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this very insightful post - I'll give this a shot if the event broadcast below doesn't work